# Feedback Bot Telegram как дополнить... библиотека PYTELEGRRAMBOTAPI Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

```
import telebot
import config


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
chatId = '-853705327'

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(chatId, message.chat.id, message.id)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

вот код..
хочу чтобы админ смог отправить ответ на сообщение, которое пришло в чат, но без понятия как это сделать.. если знаете, буду рад. Можете отправить ссылку на почитать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Когда делал использовал Inline кнопки и States
Почитать можно тут: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/custom_states.py
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)